# Tangent Space under (linear) Transformation

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, tangent-bundle, pushforward

i am looking for a confirmation of the following Lemma as well as a reference:

Let $M \subset \mathbb{R}^m $ be a smooth-manifold and $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ be a full rank matrix with $n\geq m$. Define
$$ N = \{ Ax \, |\, x \in M\}. $$
Then N is also a smooth manifold and
$$ A\mathcal{T}_x M := \{Av \, | \, v \in \mathcal{T}_x M\} = T_{Ax} N. $$

Is this correct? I would be very glad if someone could point me to a reference since unfortunatly i could not find anything that seems to be directly related. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know a reference offhand, but the statements are correct and their proofs is routine.

**Hints.**

1. The fact that $N$ is a smooth manifold follows from, e.g., the Inverse Function Theorem, or just as well the local normal form for smooth, constant-rank maps.
2. To check the claim about tangent spaces, fix any base point $x \in M$ and tangent vector $Y \in T_x M$. Then, there is a curve $\gamma : I \to M$ for some interval $I$ containing $0$ such that
   $$\gamma(0) = x \qquad \textrm{and} \qquad \gamma'(0) = Y .$$
   Now, unwind the definition of the pushforward $T_x A \cdot Y$ in terms of the curve $\gamma$ to conclude that $T_x A \cdot Y \in T_{A x} N$, and use the injectivity of $A$ to show that $T_x A$ is in fact an isomorphism $T_x M \to T_{A x} N$ (for all $X$).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It seems like this should be a standard result or even basic knowledge. I am really surprised that i dont find anything in e.g. "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds" by John M. Lee. Is there any other standard literature that i should consider?

Comment: I don't know any particular reference for this fact. Another way to think of the result is that by choosing bases of $\Bbb R^m$, $\Bbb R^n$ multiplication by $A$ has matrix representation $\pmatrix{{\bf 1}_m\\{\bf 0}_{(n-m)\times m}}$, i.e., so that the embedding $\Bbb R^m \hookrightarrow \Bbb^n$ is just the inclusion $(x_1, \ldots, x_m) \mapsto (x_1 \ldots, x_m, 0, \ldots, 0)$, which makes the claims even more intuitive.